# Is the following equation valid for a binomial coefficient?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, products

From my notes on the binomial series I deduced a formula for the value of a binomial equation using product notation:

### $ {n \choose r} = {\frac {\prod_{\lambda=0}^r(n-\lambda)} {r!}}$

I believe this holds true for $ n \in \mathbb R, r \in \mathbb Z^+$ but I have not seen it in any publications. Is this a general formula used?

Comment: The formula needs a correction. When $r=n$ LHS is $1$ and RHS is $0$.

Comment: It should be $\;\displaystyle\prod_{\lambda=0}^{r-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We can find a corresponding formula of the binomial coefficients even as *definition*  in section 5.1 *Binomial Coefficients*, formula (5.1) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
>   by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{n}{r}:=\frac{\prod_{\lambda=0}^{r-1}(n-\lambda)}{r!}\qquad n\in\mathbb{R},  r\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\\
> \end{align*}

Note the upper limit of the product is $r-1$.